# Align text under and besides a picture

Tags: html, css, image, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

Hallo once again guys.

I'm still working on a webpage, and i could use a bit of help with some html/style.

The things is that i need to place some text under, and besides a image.
The text needs to be on more then just 1 line, since it's a bit long.

I would at all time prefer if you could tell me where to implement some suggested code, instead of just saying what i should implement

Index file (DropDown.html):

```html
<html>
<body><img src="nnh-logo.gif" alt="nnh-logo" height="70" width="298"></body>
<head>
  <title>Nielsen & Nielsen Holding</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
</div>   
   <ul class="dropdown">
    <li>
 <a href="#">Firmaer</a>
 <ul>
                <li><a href="http://nielsen-nielsen.dk/">Nielsen & Nielsen</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.micro-matic.com/">Micro Matic A/S</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.senmatic.dk/">Senmatic A/S</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.nassau.dk/">Nassau A/S</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.triax.dk/">Triax A/S</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.triaxsystems.dk/">Triax Systems A/S</a></li>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <li><a href="http://www.micro-matic.dk/Jobs/job.htm">Jobs</a></li>
 <li>
  <a href="http://www.micro-matic.dk/holding/images/Holding%20Profil%20Brochure.pdf">
       Group profile</a>
    </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </body>
<body>
<img src="trappe.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 150px; 
           left: 1px; align="left" width="300" height="300">
</body>
</html>
```

Style file(Style.css:

```css
/* CSS Tweaks */
* {padding:0;margin:0;}
a img {border:0; z-index: -99; }
.clear {clear:both;}

body {font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;padding:10spx;}

.info {padding:10px;background:#f1f1f1;border:1px dotted #ccc;margin-bottom:10px;}
.info strong {display:block;}

.dropdown {list-style:none;}
.dropdown li {list-style:none;position:relative; z-index: 99;}
.dropdown li a {display:block;padding:0 10px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;height:30px;line-height:30px;}

.dropdown > li {float:left;}
.dropdown > li > a {float:left;background:#333;color:#fff;border-left:1px solid #ccc;}
.dropdown > li > a:hover,.dropdown > li:hover > a {background:#666;}

.dropdown > li ul {display:none;}

.dropdown > li:hover > ul {display:block;width:211px;position:absolute;left:0;top:25px;}
.dropdown > li > ul > li > a {display:block;background:#444;color:#ccc;}
.dropdown > li > ul > li > a:hover,.dropdown > li ul > li:hover > a {background:#666;color:#fff;}

.dropdown > li ul > li:hover > ul {display:block;width:200px;position:absolute;left:200px;top:0; z-index: 9999;}
.dropdown > li > ul > li > ul > li a {display:block;background:#555;color:#ccc;}
.dropdown > li > ul > li > ul > li a:hover {background:#444;color:#fff;}
```

Comment: Here you can see what i need it to look like:

http://gyazo.com/058fce9713991ccc4146c5eab132facd

Comment: Why do you have **two** `body` elements?

Answer (score 0):

for beside alignment use following property:

```
make the image float: left; and the text float: right;
```

Take a look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nyeung/ZV2MQ/) I used a picture online but you can just swap it out for your picture.

Comment: I see, but i still need text under the image also.

Comment: for displaying text under image you need to add alt tag in image

<img src="image.jpg" alt="image" />

Answer (score 0):

And image position can't be absolute in order to achieve what you want.

Edit:

this

```
<body>
<img src="trappe.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 150px; 
       left: 1px; align="left" width="300" height="300">
</body>
```

should be this

```
<img src="trappe.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 150px; 
       left: 1px; align="left" width="300" height="300">
```

then this

```
<body>
</div>
   <ul class="dropdown">
```

like this

```
<body>
<div>
<img src="trappe.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 150px; 
       left: 1px; align="left" width="300" height="300">
   <ul class="dropdown">
```

and last

```
.dropdown {list-style:none;}
```

should be changed like this

```
.dropdown {list-style:none; display:inline-block;}
```

This should give you starting point to beautify it all.

Comment: What should it be then?

Comment: For start, I would delete second <body> tags, change <img> position to position:relative and change <ul> display property from block to inline-block.
Then reorder them to be like this
    <img ........./>
    <ul>..........</ul>
and it will be reordered as you wish.

The rest is up to playing with margin and padding properties of those two.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean - could you make the change and then post the code again?

Comment: I've edited code. This isn't the only way but it's the way I would start coding it.

Comment: I see and have now changed it - it then brings up another question.
How do i edit so the menu is right beneath the first image, and under the menu, the last image appear.

It looks like this atm:
http://gyazo.com/6ac48f5a8b9889b7bf20c2cb81f0dac2

Answer (score 0):

add the first why you have 2 body tag ?!!! after fixing that you should use position relative with z-index:1 for image tag and for another tag you want above img use absolute position with higher z-index:2 and don`t forget use top , bottom , left or right position ...